# Como indexar um iframe no Google?

Tags: iframe, google, seo

[Este site](http://www.keysocks.com/products/womens-black-pair-wide) utiliza um `<iframe/>` para exibir seus reviews. Os reviews são inseridos e exibidos através [desta plataforma](https://www.orankl.com/).

Porém, mesmo sendo um iframe, [o Google indexa](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=%22I+loved+my+keysocks.+They+were+super+soft+and+comfortable%22).

Como isso é possível?

Comment: Cross-post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25575465/how-to-index-content-via-iframe-in-goole

Answer (score 3):

Quando o "Google" (na verdade o "robo" indexador ou *crowler*) lê a página ele também olha especialmente alguns elementos HTML que possuem algum tipo de link, seguindo então esses links e indexando-os da mesma forma. Basta um único "caminho" aberto.

Olhando no fonte da página em questão podemos ver claramente o endereço dos *reviews* no atributo `src` do `iframe:`

```html
<iframe scrolling="auto" frameborder="0" 
    src="https://www.storeya.com/widgets/couponpop?sid=011A3611" 
    id="share-coupon_frame"></iframe>
```

Quanto ao conteúdo do `iframe` aparecer como se fosse da página principal, a [Ajuda para Webmasters do Google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/34445) declara:

> Google tries to associate framed content with the page containing the frames, but we don't guarantee that we will.

Tradução (livre):

> O Google tenta associar o conteúdo em frames com a página que contém os frames, mas não garantimos isso.

Outra possibilidade seria o website apresentar um conteúdo diferente para os indexadores. Por exemplo, se o *user agent* for o *GoogleBot*, então o conteúdo é colocado *inline*, sem uso de frames.

Comment: OK, mas ele atribui o conteúdo a página que possui o <iframe> e não a página que esta no src do iframe. Muito pelo contrário, a página que esta no src nem é listada no resultado da pesquisa.

Comment: @Carlos Atualizei a resposta para refletir isso.

Comment: OK, obrigado. Mas ainda ficou obscuro o porque a página original não aparece nos resultados de busca. Em um teste que fiz ele associou o conteúdo do iframe a página que o tinha, mas também indexou a página original o "src" do iframe

Comment: @Carlos Provavelmente o site original usa algum mecanismo para impedir o Google de indexá-lo, justamente para não roubar tráfego dos clientes.

Comment: Pensei nessa hipótese também, chequei o robots.txt, headers da chamada e meta tags com noindex mas eles não estão bloqueando nada. Talvez seja alguma configuração específica no Google Web Master Tools.

Comment: Testei no [Bing](http://www.bing.com/search?q=%22I+loved+my+keysocks.+They+were+super+soft+and+comfortable%22&go=Enviar&qs=bs&form=QBRE) e ele não encontra a página que possui o <iframe> e nem a página do src, isso reforça a hipótese de que a página do src esta sendo bloqueada para os buscadores, porém ainda não sei como.

Comment: @Carlos Sugiro entrar em contato com a empresa e questioná-los. Essa investigação já fugiu bastante da pergunta original e não creio que irá obter mais detalhes das ferramentas de indexação e de buscas por aqui, já que na verdade nem o próprio Google garante esse tipo de comportamento.

Comment: Sim, já havia enviado um contato, estou aguardando eles responderem. Obrigado

Answer (score 1):

O Google indexa conteúdo através das ligações dele.

Em outras palavras, não interessa se é um iFrame, uma página normal, *endpoint* de serviço etc... Se alguém já indexado tiver um link para esse endereço, o Google o indexará.

Se não fosse indexado antes, seria indexado pelo simples fato de você ter colocado um link na sua pergunta. Na hora que o *spider* do Google passasse por esta questão (como já passou no seu crosspost), seu link seria indexado junto.

Comment: *"Se não fosse indexado antes, seria indexado pelo simples fato de você ter colocado um link na sua pergunta"* Boa!

Comment: OK, mas ele atribui o conteúdo a página que possui o <iframe> e não a página que esta no src do iframe. Muito pelo contrário, a página que esta no src nem é listada no resultado da pesquisa.

Comment: Acho que ele olha a página dentro do iFrame sim. Vou ver se há algo documentado sobre isso.